# How to display a popup message after login on sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, login, popup

How to display a popup message after login on sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FancyBox modal popup` that should be only shown **one** time for each user based on his session.

```
function openFancybox() {
setTimeout(function() {
$('#yt').trigger('click');
}, 500);
};
$(document).ready(function() {

var visited = $.cookie('visited');

if (visited == 'yes') {
return false;

// second page load, cookie active

} else {
openFancybox();

// first page load, launch fancybox

}
$.cookie('visited', 'yes', {

expires: 7 // the number of days cookie will be effective }); 
$("#yt").click(function() {
$.fancybox({
href: this.href,
type: "image",
transitionIn: "elastic",
transitionOut: "elastic"
});
return false;
});
});
```

For more details check [SHOW MODAL POPUP PER SESSION IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/10/14/load-fancybox-popup-in-first-load-of-sharepoint-site/)

---

Also, You can use `SharePoint Modal dialog` to be loaded on page load but this will need additional code to be shown only one per user session

For more details check [OPEN A MODAL DIALOG IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Comment: I will try it , tanks for your help :)

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me in SharePoint 2016 :(

Comment: Don't worry, Just tell me what the issue you have faced on 2016? BTW, you have mentioned 2013 have you tried it on 2013?

Comment: i have a problem with cookie
var visited = $.cookie('visited'); 
alert(visited);
=> undefined

Comment: thanks very much , with some modification it's working :)